# Where did quitSafely() go?

Tags: android

I'm using a looper in the following way:

```
Thread oneThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {     
                Looper.prepare();
                handler = new Handler(){
                     public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                         // process incoming messages here
                     }
                };
                Looper.loop();
            }
        }, "FirstThread");
        oneThread.start();
```

I took a look in the API and wanted to use the quitSafely() method found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#quitSafely%28%29
but when I wanted to do

```
handler.getLooper().quitSafely()
```

The method is never proposed!
Has it been deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The method is never proposed!

As is noted in the documentation, `quitSafely()` was added in API Level 18. Presumably, your build target (e.g., Project > Properties > Android in Eclipse) is set to a lower API level.

Comment: Now I just need to wait for the Jelly Bean 4.3 update for my phone :(